# Ошибка со стеком: Thread stack overrun

Tags: стек, sql

```
update `t_map_atms` set phone='3e43' WHERE id=37
```

Для проверки дала такой вот простенький запрос.

Вышло:

> #1436 - Thread stack overrun: 8240 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed. Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.

Гуглила. Нашла вариант, как исправитья: в файле my.cnf надо одну строчку привести к виду

```
 thread_stack = 256K
```

такого файла не нашла, нашла только my.ini. Подобной строки нет, сама вставила (для эксперемента), но не работает. 
Что мне делать?

Comment: попробуйте создать файл и добавть в него нужную вам строку

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как бы смешно это ни звучало, я нашла второй my.ini. С какого фонаря у меня их два, я не знаю, но нужную строку в нем я нашла и изменила. Все теперь пашет.

Comment: с чистой совестью можете принять свой ответ как верный. только укажите путь к конфиг файлу. может кому пригодится :)