# Триггер не работает в Mysql.  Thread stack overrun ...to specify a bigger stack

Tags: триггер, mysql

Добрый вечер.
Написал триггер Insert в Mysql, который для наглядности, ничего не делает (!).

```
CREATE 
    DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
TRIGGER test.TriggerInsert
    AFTER INSERT
    ON test.tableforinsert
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
END
```

Только пытаюсь вставить в таблицу данные - он ругается:

> Thread stack overrun......to specify a bigger stack.

В MSSQL делал триггеры, а здесь переполнение уже от того, что просто ничего нет - что-то непонятно. Погуглил. Так и не нашёл ответ.  
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело?
Спасибо.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/139594

Правда, на хостинге, может, и нельзя менять. Но получается вообще какой-то бред. Все таблицы пустые, а у него переполнение.




Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка со стеком: Thread stack overrun](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/139594/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-thread-stack-overrun)