# MySQL #1436 - Thread stack overrun

Tags: mysql

Дубликат вопроса [Триггер не работает в Mysql.  Thread stack overrun ...to specify a bigger stack](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/363484/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-mysql-thread-stack-overrun-to-specify-a-bigger-stack)

Вот только у меня сайт на хостинге, и изменение конфига - не решение.
Господа, что это вообще за Дичь?! Таблицы пустые, триггер:

```
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `clients_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON  `clients` 
FOR EACH
ROW INSERT INTO calls
SET client_id = NEW.id,
proccessed =0;
```

Comment: на многих хостингах тригеры не разрешены

Comment: вопрос имеет смысл адресовать техподдержке хостинга.